# operator + overload c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, priority-queue, dijkstra

I am attempting to code a small scale Dijktra's Algorithm using a map, a priory queue and a list. I know there many many issues with this code but at the moment I am mainly concerned about overloading the + operator to add to objects. I am not familiar with overloading and any help would be greatly appreciated. I am attempting two add two objects (nodes) based on the private member cost which is an integer.

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <map>
#include <queue>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

class node
{
public:
    node();
    node(char n, int l){
       name = n; cost =l;}

    void display()const{cout<<"name = "<<name<<" cost = "<<cost<<"\n";}
    char getName()const{return name;}
    int getCost() {return cost;}

    node operator+(const node& n){node N1;N1.cost = this->cost + N1.cost; return N1;} //<---

private:
    char name;
    int cost;
};

bool operator<(node a, node b)
{
  return a.getCost()> b.getCost();
}

int main()
{

    map<node,node>::iterator mapItr;
    map<node,node> myMap;
    priority_queue<node> que;
    list<node> solution;
    list<node>::iterator listItr;
    list<node> checkList;
    node * nptr;

    myMap.insert(pair<node, node>(node('A',5),node('B',5)));
    myMap.insert(pair<node, node>(node('A',6),node('C',6)));
    myMap.insert(pair<node, node>(node('B',3),node('C',3)));
    myMap.insert(pair<node, node>(node('B',7),node('E',7)));
    myMap.insert(pair<node, node>(node('C',2),node('E',2)));
    myMap.insert(pair<node, node>(node('C',4),node('D',4)));
    myMap.insert(pair<node, node>(node('D',5),node('E',5)));
    myMap.insert(pair<node, node>(node('D',10),node('G',10)));
    myMap.insert(pair<node, node>(node('E',9),node('G',9)));
    myMap.insert(pair<node, node>(node('E',4),node('F',4)));
    myMap.insert(pair<node, node>(node('F',2),node('G',2)));


    solution.push_back(node('A',0));

    do
    {

    listItr=solution.begin();

        do
        {   nptr = &*listItr;

            for(mapItr=myMap.begin();mapItr!=myMap.end();mapItr++)
            {
                if(nptr->getName()==mapItr->first.getName())
                {
                    que.push(mapItr->second);
                }

            }
            if( nptr->getName()!= que.top().getName())

                 {

                   que.top()= (*que.top())+(*nptr);//<---- error here
                    solution.push_back(que.top());

                    que.pop();
                    listItr++;
                    solution.pop_front();

                 }
                 else
                 {que.pop();
                 listItr++;}

        }
        while(listItr!= solution.end() );
    }
    while (!que.empty());


return 0;
}
```

The error message is:

no match for 'opeerator*' in '*que.std::priorty_queue<_Tp, _Sequence, _Compare>::top >()'

Comment: `que.top()` returns a reference, not a pointer. The issue is with trying to dereference it.

Comment: Edited ... took some unnecessary code out. I guess what I really what to know is how to add the cost of the first element in the P-queue to the cost of the solution?

Answer (score 2):

The real cause of the error you got is that you try to dereference `que.top()`. `que.top()` already returns the top value by const reference. The solution is to replace `(*que.top())` with `que.top()`.

You also need to create another node to put the result, since `top` returns a const reference. So change it to `node n = queue.top() + *nptr;` Since you add the result to a list you could just do `solution.push_back(que.top() + *nptr);` as well. Change `operator+` to be a const member function too

Comment: Removing the dereference operator doesn't fix the error, I was thinking 
que.top()= que.top()+ *nptr; 
but this gives me a 
"passing 'const value_type as 'this' ...... discards qualifiers [-fpermissive] error

Comment: Ah right, `top` returns a const reference. You need to copy it to another node. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, I tried your suggestions. I made the operator+ a const function, and also changed the push_back statement. Now I'm getting 

"undefined reference to 'node::node()'
Build failed: 1 error, 0 warnings, etc. etc. Any thoughts?

Comment: These are just multiple errors that already existed. You never implemented the default constructor for `node` in this case. You just declared it. I recommend you spend some time trying to understand what the error messages mean. Most of them are very clear about what's missing.

Answer (score 1):

Change in operator+ code :

```
node operator+(const node& n)
{
    node N1;N1.cost = this->cost + N1.cost; return N1;
}
```

N1.cost by n.cost